# Find all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such $x^2 - 3(y^2 - 1)^2 = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such $x^2 - 3(y^2 - 1)^2 = 1$.

My try:
$\frac{x^2-1}{3} =(y^2-1)^2$, so $x=\left\{ 2,7,26...\right\} $

and many y. Is it correct?

Comment: What are these $2,7,26 \dots$?

Comment: The equation asks all ?? How have left dots there

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee yes, i know, but how it use?